# How to omit aberrant results in the internal concatenation of a `.groupby().apply()` results on python polars?

Tags: python-polars

I have a data frame which requires several operations to compute a final result. These operations could be simplified by encapsulating them in a `.groupby().apply()` call. (I don't mind here the loss of optimizations by switching from rust to python when using a python function, as my only objective is to simplify code and not speed.)

The issue is that in some of the groups there is no result, not by error but just because those specific group contents don't fulfill certain criteria (e.g not enough cases, lack of some other factors, etc.).

The technical reason for the problem is that my current function returns a data frame in a standard schema which is different from the input's and obviously different from the `return None` of the aberrant cases.

One working solution is to return an empty data frame with such standard schema, but is rather cumbersome since the operations performed by the function are still under heavy development, have not converged and even more so they could change with the input data frame (also arguably solvable).

I am aware that there could be different solutions at the level of the UDF but having the `.groupby().apply()` ignore certain results would be very flexible.

Is there a way to return an object that won't be included in the final, internal concatenation performed by `.groupby().apply()`?

Toy example

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        "color": ["blue", "green", "green", "red", "red"],
        "shape": ["square", "triangle", "square", "triangle", "square"],
    }
)
print(df)
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ id  ┆ color ┆ shape    │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str      │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ blue  ┆ square   │
│ 1   ┆ green ┆ triangle │
│ 2   ┆ green ┆ square   │
│ 3   ┆ red   ┆ triangle │
│ 4   ┆ red   ┆ square   │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

An extremely simple UDF to illustrate the point:

```
def udf(df):
    result = df.filter(pl.col('id')<3)
    # if the result doesn't fulfill a given criteria is "aberrant" 
    # in this example the group 'red' has no element 'id' smaller than 3
    if result.shape[0] < 1:
        return None
       #return pl.DataFrame() # fails too

    # actual results have a different schema than the input df
    return result.select('id', 'color')
```

Representative error case:

```
df.groupby('color').apply(udf)

thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Could net get DataFrame attribute '_df'. Make sure that you return a DataFrame object.: PyErr { type: <class 'AttributeError'>, value: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute '_df'"), traceback: None }', src/dataframe.rs:1106:68
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PanicException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[91], line 1
----> 1 df.groupby('color').apply(udf)

File miniconda3/envs/mc2b2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/dataframe/groupby.py:336, in GroupBy.apply(self, function)
    332 else:
    333     raise TypeError("Cannot call `apply` when grouping by an expression.")
    335 return self.df.__class__._from_pydf(
--> 336     self.df._df.groupby_apply(by, function, self.maintain_order)
    337 )

PanicException: Could net get DataFrame attribute '_df'. Make sure that you return a DataFrame object.: PyErr { type: <class 'AttributeError'>, value: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute '_df'"), traceback: None }
```

The expected result would be :

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ color │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ green │
│ 2   ┆ green │
│ 0   ┆ blue  │
└─────┴───────┘
```

Comment: What should the output be from your example? With just `return result.select('id', 'color')` and no shape check/early return - you get `id: [0, 1, 2]`

Comment: Yes. I should add that to complete the example. Thanks for the question.

Comment: If you just do `result = ...; return result.select('id', 'color')` then you get the expected output.

Comment: Sure, that would work since for the current simplified example we don't do much. Perhaps I went too far in the simplification of the UDF. Your suggestion would work since polars is returning the right schema. In the real life scenario it wouldn't hold.

Comment: Hm okay, I guess I'm missing the bigger picture - will re-read again, thanks.